# Unable to Manually Add New Packages to Sublime Text 3

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext3, package-control

I'm new to using Ubuntu.  I installed **Sublime Text 3** and **Package Control**.  I'm trying to install **SideBarEnhancements** but can't figure out how.  Instructions say to clone the directory from github into the Packages folder but when I try to do this, it says I do not have permissions.  Steps taken to try this:

1. Downloaded the zip from here
   https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements.
2. Copy zip to `opt/sublime_text/packages`

I tried changing folder permissions in terminal but it would not let me do chmod saying I didn't have permissions.  Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the packages folder you're trying to put this in `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`? If not, you're putting it in the wrong place (there is another packages folder with the sublime provided packages that is probably not accessible to non-root). However, if you have installed PackageControl you should use `Preferences > Package Control > Package Control: Install package" to install packages where possible; the package that you're trying to install is available via Package Control.

Answer (score 1):

You are copying to the wrong directory.

Copy to `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`.

To find where the Packages directory from Sublime Text go to `Menu > Preferences > Browse Packages...`.

Rather than downloading and copying to the directory, you can add SideBarEnhancements as a Package Control respository. This will give auto updates.

- Main `Menu > Preferences > Package Control`
- Select `Add repository`
- Then paste `https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements/tree/st3`
- Now you can install SideBarEnhancements normally via Package Control i. open the Command Palette <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and install SideBarEnhancements via the `Package Control: Install Package` command.